# NSMutableArray always replace old objects with last one

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I'm a newbie in Objective-C programming and I got a problem with my NSMutableArray ...

When I make a first try, my datas are well saved, but if I wanna make a second try, the first one is overwrite by the new and the new is also saved.

An exemple to understand :

1st try :

```
Tabobjets : (
        {
        Contact = 1;
        DateARendre = 1;
        DateJour = "2013-03-19 19:27:29 +0000";
        Nom = 1;
        Rendu = 0;
        Titre = 1;
    }
)
```

2nd try :

```
Tabobjets : (
        {
        Contact = 2;
        DateARendre = 2;
        DateJour = "2013-03-19 19:27:40 +0000";
        Nom = 2;
        Rendu = 0;
        Titre = 2;
    },
        {
        Contact = 2;
        DateARendre = 2;
        DateJour = "2013-03-19 19:27:40 +0000";
        Nom = 2;
        Rendu = 0;
        Titre = 2;
    }
)
```

Here is my code

```
@interface SecondViewController () {
    NSMutableDictionary *tabObjet;
    NSMutableArray *tabObjets;
    NSString *appFile;
}

@end

@implementation SecondViewController

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    // the path to write file
    appFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Bigre.plist"];

    if (tabObjets == nil) {
        tabObjets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:appFile];
    }

    if (tabObjet == nil) {
        tabObjet = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)saisieReturn :(id)sender{
    [sender resignFirstResponder];

    NSLog(@"Tabobjet avant : %@",tabObjet);
    NSLog(@"Tabobjets avant : %@",tabObjets);

    //inscription dans un dictionnaire
    [tabObjet setObject:_titreObjet.text forKey:@"Titre"];
    [tabObjet setObject:_nomPersonne.text forKey:@"Nom"];
    [tabObjet setObject:_infoContact.text forKey:@"Contact"];
    [tabObjet setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"DateJour"];
    [tabObjet setObject:_dateARendre.text forKey:@"DateARendre"];
    [tabObjet setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"Rendu"];

    int numItems = [tabObjets count];
    [tabObjets insertObject:tabObjet atIndex:numItems];

    NSLog(@"Tabobjet apres : %@",tabObjet);
    NSLog(@"Tabobjets apres : %@",tabObjets);

    //écriture dans un fichier plist
    [tabObjets writeToFile:appFile atomically:YES];
}

@end
```

Thanks a lot for the help :)

Comment: Please explain the problem a little better. And FYI, TabObjets is a mutable array, not a dictionary, so its behaviour is as expected. Did I miss something?

Comment: Sorry but i'm not English ^^ and got some problem to be very explicit.
So as you said, it's normal if my datas are overwrite with the NSMutableArray ?

Comment: Yes, it is normal. At the first run you add an object and save the array. At the second run you read the array with the first object, add a new one, so the array has two items. Then you save that. As it should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You overwrite your `tabObjet`. Just declare it inside `saisieReturn:` and change it to

```
- (IBAction)saisieReturn :(id)sender{
    [sender resignFirstResponder];

    NSLog(@"Tabobjets avant : %@",tabObjets);

    //inscription dans un dictionnaire
    tabObjet = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [tabObjet setObject:_titreObjet.text forKey:@"Titre"];
    [tabObjet setObject:_nomPersonne.text forKey:@"Nom"];
    [tabObjet setObject:_infoContact.text forKey:@"Contact"];
    [tabObjet setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"DateJour"];
    [tabObjet setObject:_dateARendre.text forKey:@"DateARendre"];
    [tabObjet setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"Rendu"];

    [tabObjets addObject:tabObjet];

    NSLog(@"Tabobjet apres : %@",tabObjet);
    NSLog(@"Tabobjets apres : %@",tabObjets);

    //écriture dans un fichier plist
    [tabObjets writeToFile:appFile atomically:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are modifying the same mutable dictionary every time when you are trying to add new one. Modify your line like:

```
[tabObjets insertObject:[tabObjet copy] atIndex:numItems];
```

Comment: I choose the Tilo's one, but thanks a lot, it's working well ;)